# Text View in a nested linear layout is not shown in a custom notification content view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

My layout file

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/MarginHalf"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notification_logos"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Margin2x"
        android:id="@+id/notification_body"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/notification_side_padding"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/notification_image"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notification_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Ds6"
            android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textColor="@color/notification_ds6_header"
            tools:text="Test Item *** Please Do Not Buy/Bid ***29b66b4accd747f4adc48832ebaeffbc"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MarginQuarter"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/MarginEighth"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Ds6"
                android:textColor="@color/notification_ds6_secondary_text"
                tools:text="This is a long winded text which needs to be wrapped for good measure."
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:ignore="Deprecated"/>

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/notification_countdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="left|bottom"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Ds6"
                android:textColor="@color/notification_ds6_secondary_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizeSmall"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="10:02 AM" />

            <Chronometer
                android:id="@+id/notification_countdown_60s"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/alert_color"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Ds6"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizeSmall"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="10:02 AM" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification_time_expired"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/notification_ds6_disabled_text"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Ds6"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizeSmall"
                android:visibility="visible" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks like in a preview.

[image: Layout Preview]

I am rendering this layout as a custom content view. This is how it looks on the device.

[image]

My code to render the layout

```
    RemoteViews rootView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_collapsed);
rootView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, rawNotification.getTitle());

rootView.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_content, rawNotification.getCountdownBody());
        long now = new ClockWall().instant();

        NotificationAction collapsedAction = rawNotification.getCollapsedClickAction();
        if (collapsedAction != null)
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(collapsedAction.getAction(ebayContext.getContext()));
        notificationBuilder.setCustomContentView(rootView);

        // Build notification and the call the notify function.
```

I don't know what I have done wrong.

Comment: Hve u tried to print the value of `rawNotification.getCountdownBody()` in `logs`

Comment: Yes. It is not null and is a valid string.

Comment: In fact, when I expand the notification, it shows me the body.